# I am stuck on the motheboard's logo after trying to boot from an USB drive

Tags: boot, usb, bios

I recently build my own computer and I want to install Windows 10 on it so I created a bootable USB drive with the Windows "Media Creation Tool" but when I try to boot on the drive in UFI I get stuck on the motherbord's logo (without the spiny dots).

I am able do get into the Bios and the boot menu but when I ask my computer to boot on the USB drive it gets stuck. It seams like when people have issues and see the motherboard's logo for ever, they have the problem before getting in the Bios.
I tried selecting the USB drive in legacy bios but now I get stuck with the Windows logo (still without spiny dots).

I tried:

- unpluging every thing connected to USB
- reinstaling the Windows install media
- creating a bootable drive with Rufus and a Windows ISO
- taking of the RAM sticks one by one
- enabling the safe boot mode
- installing ubuntu (didn't work)
- booting with an other USB stick (both UEFI and Legacy Bios)

I am desperate please help me (T-T) !

Comment: First of all.. use the Media Creation Tool (like you are doing).. not Rufus for this task.. Make sure your firmware is set to let you boot from USB media.  Try booting in legacy mode? .. does that work?  Try booting the stick in another PC... if that doesnt work (I see that you tried the media creation twice).  Try a different stick.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I just tried every thing you have proposed but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I just understood what has gone wrong. When I built my computer I buyed all the components except the graphics card (because I didn't want to use half of by budget for it) so I used an old graphics card (nvidia quadro fx 580) and I just realized that the graphics card doesn't support UEFI. So I am just doing to wait until I can afford a graphics card.

Comment: Why not simply install using MBR and legacy mode?  UEFI won't make your computer run better.